# Measuring # of dropped packets for individual TCP connections

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I'm interested in measuring network performance. I have a little tool to do speed tests and such but I would be very interested in measuring the quality of the connection by seeing how many packets were dropped or re-transmitted.

I know that using netstat and such I can get aggregate numbers, but how do I do it for individual connections?

- Language: C (not counting on API but hey!)
- OS: Linux (if there is a method that also works for Mac/Win that'd be awesome!)

Comment: Might be able to do something like that by setting up a filter in [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: So it is not possible to figure this out without external tools? The problem is that I want to flash my program onto my dd-wrt eventually so I can't really afford wireshark ...

Comment: I don't know if there are APIs to get the information you want. Worst case, you could download the Wireshark source code and see how they do it . . .

Answer (score 0):

you can use tcpdump and listen to a specific port, and it works as wireshark (applying filters for specific protocols, ports, network etc )and if I am not wrong then I think wireshark also use tcpdump on backend.